# закрыть блок по клику вне его, но с учетом исключения элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

Ситуация такая.. Есть стандартное решение закрытия блока по клику вне его области. Оно работает, но на данном блоке есть дочерний элемент, по клику на который должен закрываться главный блок. На данный момент, по клику на этот дочерний элемент ничего не происходит. Как в данном примере кода установить исключение для дочернего элемента. Пробовал вот так - $(".menu_close").has(e.target).length !== 0, и не помогает, а так же $(".menu_close").has(e.target).length == 1. Та же ситуация.

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
    if (!$(".header_content_one_menu").is(e.target) && $(".header_content_one_menu").has(e.target).length === 0) {
       $('#header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
```

```css
#header_menu_adaptive {
    display: none;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999999;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button > span {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.05s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button> span::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(0);
    visibility: visible;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    visibility: visible;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
    content: '';
    top: 28px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #B72A20;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_content_one_menu {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button > span, .header_menu_adaptive_button> span::before, .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #B72A20;
    font-family: RobotoCondensed;
    letter-spacing: 2.4px;
    transition-duration: .25s;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 11112;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button > span::before {
    content: '';
    bottom: 29px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #B72A20;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}



.header_content_one_menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox">
<label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span>меню</span>
</label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">                       
<li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">111</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">222</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">333</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">444</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">555</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">666</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Когда люди наконец то будут решать подобные задачи на нативном js? Нету никакого желания в этом копаться. Добавьте свой html для наглядности

Comment: Добавил css и html. Ситуация в том, что при клике на "крестик" меню не закрывается, а при клике вне меню закрывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще просто проверять, пришелся ли клик снаружи контейнера, как вы это делали ранее и добавить обработчик для клика на крестик:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
    if (!$(".header_content_one_menu").is(e.target) && $(".header_content_one_menu").has(e.target).length === 0) {
       $('#header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
$("крестик").on('click',function (e){
...
});
```

Comment: изначально я подумал, что речь идет о крестике у окна, но даже если это другой дочерний элемент, принцип тот же